# Tricky aggregation using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Am new to pandas and curious if this is too tricky to accomplish using it.

**Example input:**

```
time       person   game_id   won
-----------------------------------
12:34:01   John     3         False
12:34:04   Ringo    2         True
12:35:05   John     3         False
12:36:01   John     3         True
12:36:12   Ringo    3         True
12:36:41   Paul     4         False
12:37:01   George   2         False
12:37:41   George   2         False
```

It shows a number of persons playing a number of games over time.
The won column indicates if the person won or not at that time.

What I want as output is how many people won each game **at least once**.
But also how many people played the game and **never** won.

**Example Output:**

```
game_id   won     count
-----------------------
2         True    1
          False   1
3         True    2
          False   0
4         True    0
          False   1
```

Comment: Nope, not too tricky.  You can do it in a few lines in a few ways: I used `groupby` and `.nunique()` to do the hard part.  (It seemed easier to me to count the number of total players and ever-winners and then to subtract them to get the never-winners.)

Comment: Hi Yasir! Without using pandas I'd do a method which run roughly in order n*log(n). It works as follows using e.g. dictionaries:

First I'd sort the rows by person, then by game_id and last by won. Then loop through all rows and increment a counter for (game_id, won=True) if there is a "True" entry. Else I would increment (game_id, won=False) by one if there are only False entries.

Finally I'd print out the resulting dictionary.

Figured there possibly is a way more elegant way to do this using pandas.

Comment: Thanks DSM! If you could share some details that would be amazing. Trying to do this for a laaaaarge dataset. So speed is key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More or less what @DSM was saying:

```
In [3]: grouped = df.groupby('game_id')

In [4]: won = grouped.won.sum()

In [5]: DataFrame({True: won, False: grouped.person.nunique() - won}).stack()
Out[5]: 
game_id       
2        False    1
         True     1
3        False    0
         True     2
4        False    1
         True     0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks Chang She, pandas superstar!

Answer (score 4):

```
s1 = (~df.groupby(["game_id", "person"]).won.agg(np.any)).groupby(level=0).sum()
s2 = df.groupby(["game_id", "won"]).person.agg(lambda s:s.nunique())
df2 = s2.unstack()
df2[False] = s1
df2.fillna(0).unstack().swaplevel(0, 1).sort_index()
```

Comment: Thanks HYRY. You also handle the case of multiple games won by the same person which is excellent.